# How ORM implementations distinguish between database fields and class' member variables

Tags: php, orm

Let's take a Laravel's ORM implementation (Eloquent) as an example. However, this question applies to all the ORM solutions I know.

A model (User for example) extends Laravel's Eloquent class, and we have functions like "find" or "save". In the docs ( http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage ) we have the following code snippet:

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();
```

I tried to analyze this "save" method, with no success (it's a very big class).

The question is - how this method distinguish between database fields and class' member variables, let's say that my User class looks like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent{
 public $someVariable;
}
```

How the "save" method knows that "someVariable" is not a field in database, which it then updates in database or uses in "insert" statement? But, on the other hand, "name" variable IS such a field?

Comment: `name`, in this case, is created via magic methods. It doesn't exist in the class and it never will. `save()` is on the other hand a defined method of that class and, although I'm not sure, it's probably `final` too so it can't be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed there is a __set magic method and it updates the "$attributes" array. So indeed it works like this. Thanks again!